# Checking through an arraylist and return a boolean result

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean, matching

I'm facing a problem whereby `retrieveLoginData()` is always returning `false`
How do I make it so that it returns the value of my `if-else-statement`? Thanks a lot!

```
private ArrayList<String> login = new ArrayList<String>();

    public boolean retrieveLoginData(LoginRecord lr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < login.size(); i++) {

        if (lr.getLoginName().equals(login.get(i)))

    return true;}// There's a duplicate in the arraylist
    return false; // Returns false if there are no duplicates
```

}

Comment: provide minimal testable code. what is `login` here. It should be `if (lr.getLoginName().equals(login.get(i).getLoginName()))`

Comment: Code is legit maybe flow never gets into if

Answer (score 0):

Because your if condition is never valid. May be you want to you use equalsignorecase

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Thanks a lot

Comment: What I was trying to suggest: Is this possible that login names may be same but different in case (small case, upper case) .. that can be the problem. For example is user1 same as USER1 or different ? In gmail user and USER is same.

Comment: Oh, in my case, it's not case sensitive. So as long there's a match in the array, it returns a `true` value

Answer (score 0):

`retrieveLoginData()` returns false all time because you only assign ArrayList login and don't give any value to the login.For this login has empty and it size is 0 and loop is exit when it 1st time enter into loop block.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so if the login ID doesn't exist in the arraylist, it will then be created and stored in it. If it exists already, it will return `false`